# How to negate a particular pattern in string using regex?

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have a string where i want to extract a particular pattern only.

```
x<-c("N4553","3805U","celeron N4553","applheddd")
gregextract <- gregexpr('\\bceleron\\b|\\bN[0-9]+\\b',x,perl=TRUE)
size1<- regmatches(x,gregextract,invert = FALSE)
```

It extracts both the occurrences of `N`, I need only `celeron` to be extracted(where a combination of `celeron N4533` occurs) without `N4533`. I cannot remove `N[0-9]` pattern as it is used of other occurrences in different rows.

Comment: There is nothing extracted so far on my end

Comment: @Onyambu - works for me - look at `size1` output

Comment: ohh I see what you mean. use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`

Comment: try looking up regex capture groups in r. Seems to be plenty out there

Comment: Do you want to get the whole character string if there are 2 whole words, `celeron` and `N+digits` regardless of order? Try https://ideone.com/iTAFYY

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- If "Celeron N4553" occurs , i need only the celeron and restrict the regex not to extract N4553 from "Celeron N4553". However i have individual occurrences of "N4553" where it should extract "N4553" .